# Pinging localhost in Swift w/ Xcode

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, api, request

Eventually my Swift frontend will make API calls to an external server, but in the development process, I want to test things locally on my computer. How do I reach my localhost server from Xcode? At this point I'm just trying to ensure contact--I don't need to actually retrieve anything yet.

So far I have the following code:

```
let urlString = "MY_IP_ADDRESS"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!

do {
    try url.checkResourceIsReachable()
    print("Success!")
} catch {
    print("Failure!")
}
```

In the `urlString` variable, I tried my actual IP Address. I also tried `localhost:4001/hello` where 4001 was the port my node.js server was listening on and I defined `/hello`. Am I using the wrong address, the wrong code, or is there no way to contact my local machine from Xcode?

Comment: localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you specifying a protocol? Your url should have a http or something at the beginning…

Comment: @jnpdx a scheme

Comment: so I'll need to add like `curl` or something?

Comment: A URL consists of a scheme, a host, a port, a path, a query, etc.  The scheme is the part before a colon ":".  Common schemes include "http". "https", "file", "mailto" etc.  Your URL strings did not include a scheme (except `localhost:4001/hello` where the scheme was "localhost").   You could reach a web server (if one is running) on your local machine with the URL "http://localhost/" or "http://127.0.0.1".   But without a scheme, you do not have a valid URL.

Comment: So as mentioned by @ScottThompson, and assuming your local server is serving `http`, add a scheme to your url like `http://localhost:4001/hello`

Comment: That makes sense, but when I ran it my do-catch was still catching an error, meaning `url.checkResourceIsReachable` is throwing an error. Is this working on your guys' machines? Could the problem be with my node.js server?

Comment: My node.js server works fine when I `curl` it from the command line, by the way.

Comment: Also, with adding the scheme like you mentioned, the url worked from google chrome. Is the problem with the `url.checkResourceIsReachable` function?

Comment: @JohnSorensen Have you set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES` in your Info.plist?

Comment: No. Is that needed for it to work?

Comment: @JohnSorensen I think it's a low-cost experiment to do. That key is required to load non-secure HTTP connections. I don't know that localhost is excluded from that.

Comment: So I moved my code into a Swift file tied to my app (so Info.plist will apply--I assume things are different for playgrounds) and entered `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` as a key in `Info.plist` and set the value to `YES`. It still didn't work for me, but I wouldn't be surprised if I did something wrong. Is it working on your machine @jnpdx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `print(error)`  in your `catch` block (which is always a good practice -- `print("Failure!")` doesn't tell you *why* the `catch` block was invoked) you'll notice that there's an error telling you:

> The file couldn’t be opened because the specified URL type isn’t supported.

Although it isn't explicitly said, I think the implication here is that `checkResourceIsReachable` is for filesystem URLs -- not remote `http` requests.

Instead, use a system of verifying the URL is reachable meant for remote resources.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class CheckURL : ObservableObject {
    enum URLResult : String {
        case unknown, unreachable, reachable
    }
    
    @Published var urlReachable : URLResult = .unknown
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    func verifyURL(urlPath: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlPath) else {
            assertionFailure("Invalid URL")
            self.urlReachable = .unknown
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url).tryMap({ (_ , response: URLResponse) -> URLResult in
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 {
                return .reachable
            } else {
                return .unreachable
            }
        })
        .replaceError(with: .unreachable)
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main).sink { result in
            self.urlReachable = result
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var urlChecker = CheckURL()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Reachable? \(urlChecker.urlReachable.rawValue)")
            .onAppear {
                    urlChecker.verifyURL(urlPath: "http://localhost:4001/")
            }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you'll want to make sure you have `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` set to `YES` in your Info.plist

Comment: My Xcode is not able to find `AnyCancellable?`. Do need to import a package for this?

Comment: Yes -- `import Combine`

Comment: Ok, I did that and it worked!

Comment: I'll need to go through your code and understand what's happening but I'm definately able to link up with my local node.js server

Comment: All it does is send a `HEAD` http request to the URL. If it gets a 200 response, it says it is reachable. If not, it is unreachable. You could make it more robust by responding differently to different error codes, etc., but this seemed like enough for your purpose of just seeing if you could get a connection to the URL.

Comment: Yeah that definately works for my purpose